# C# Application crashing upon closing custom form

Tags: c#, xml, winforms, datagridview, crash

I have went through different questions and didn't really find anything that suited my problem, but I also didn't exactly know what to look up to get any results either, so I may have missed some entries. If anyone could link to something that might be of assistance, I would greatly appreciate it.

I'll start off by posting a code example that I'm using (Is not the exact code, as I cannot release this) that I think is causing the application to crash.

```
using (var editForm = new frmEditableText("Alarm Note", "Title"))
{
    var result = editForm.ShowDialog(this);
    if (result == DialogResult.OK)
    {
        string temp = editForm.ReturnValue;
        string xPath = String.Format("AlarmsDb/Alarm[Id = '{0}']/Notes", alarmID);
        if (!Tools.OverWriteXMLSingleNote(alarm_xml_path, xPath, temp))
            logErr("Error overwiting XML alarm: {0}", xPath);
        AlarmDb.SetNote(alarmID, temp);
    }
}
```

Tools is a private codebase that houses miscellaneous universal tools that get ported from project to project.

I'm not exactly sure what is going on. I know this code works as it is working on all other code lines I have used it in.

The only thing that is different is the PC itself.

The way it's setup is in a datagridview, on cell click it pops up a form for you to put your notes for that specific row and save them.

Once the form pops up, I close it and immediately the app crashes and won't recover, but there is no exception being reported either.

This only happens when not running through visual studio (matters not if it's a release or debug build, only if it is or isn't running in visual studio).

I'm sure I may have missed some details, please let me know if there is any other information you need from me, but this about sums up my issue.

***EDIT:***

With some further debugging, I've added multiple log statements in all places possible that would have to do with the form closing, opening, doing it's intended purpose.

What I've found is the `FormClosing` event makes it all the way through.

`ShowDialog(this)` is expected to return a `DialogResult` enum value, but hangs at the point of which it is actually attempting to return this value causing the application to freeze up.

I've also found that setting thread priority to AboveNormal for the thread which ends up calling the form gets rid of the issue. However I do not think that is a good enough solution.

Comment: Since your proprietary code looks like the likely culprit, I'm afraid this might be impossible to answer without knowing precisely what it does.

Comment: It can be an exception thrown on a thread that is not directly connected with user action (it can start with click and then goes on it's own way).
Add some try.. catch blocks to detect area where exception is thrown and try to narrow it to single line code.

Comment: So I've been debugging this for a while now.

I've added log statements in multiple places, I have try catches everywhere.

What I've found from the log statements was that it never returns from the call to `editForm.ShowDialog(this)`.

I have a FormClosing event that has log statements after every second line of code being executed, and they all get logged, until the `ShowDialog(this)` is expected to return a value.

tl;dr It's hanging at `var result = editFormShowDialog(this)` returning a value as I've found from having an exorbitant amount of log statements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears there was an oversight on my end, although I'm still not certain if this is the correct way to resolve my issue.

I don't have very much knowledge on the whole ApartmentState being MTA or STA, or how to identify when which should be used.

What did solve my issue though was going through all the threads that are spun off my main thread and setting their ApartmentState to STA, which I thought was already done from a previous codeline to resolve another issue I was having (such is the problem with collaboration).

But yes, I went through the entirety of my solution and found all instances of new threads being created and explicitly setting their ApartmentState to STA has resolved the crashing issue.

If anyone can provide some good material defining the differences and when to use either, or how to identify when one should be used over the other, it would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score -1):

did you try subscribing to the AppDomain.UnhandledException event? You can use this as a final catch all (no pun intended) and log to a file the exception see 
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/system.appdomain.unhandledexception(v=vs.110).aspx

Alternatively/additionally - did you look in the event viewer?

Good luck

Comment: This seems more like asking questions than providing an answer.